# mongo how to update a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Given the following schema from a collection named user:

```
{
    "email": "somebody@gmail.com", 
    "classes": [
        {
            "className": "AAAA1111",
            "marks": [72, 85, 64],
            "grades": [20, 40, 30]
        },
        {
            "className": "BBBB2222",
            "marks": [12, 25, 43],
            "grades": [32, 42, 32]
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I add another class to the person with the email of `somebody@gmail.com?`

For example, how do I add the subdocument

```
{
    "className": "CCCC3333",
    "marks": [75, 85, 95],
    "grades": [20, 30, 50]
}
```

whilst keeping the existing information? How would I delete class `AAAA1111` without affecting the rest of the document? I am new to mongo and have had trouble with the solutions I have tried. What is the best practice?

Comment: Please give us the schema model too.

Comment: Is "users" a collection name, or is it a key in a document?

Comment: @RashadIbrahimov my apologies, it is the collection name.

Comment: @errorreplicating In this case my answer solves your issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Push** operation to add new class to array:

```
db.users.update({"email": "somebody@gmail.com"}, {
    $push: {
        "classes": {
            "className": "CCCC3333",
            "marks": [75, 85, 95],
            "grades": [20, 30, 50]
        }
    }
});
```

**Pull** operation to remove specific class from array:

```
db.users.update({"email": "somebody@gmail.com"}, {
    $pull: {
        "classes": {
            "className": "AAAA1111"
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To add another another class to the person with the email of `somebody@gmail.com`, use the **[`positional $`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** operator in your update document since this  identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array. As you are updating a field within an embedded document, you would require the use of the dot notation. When using the **[dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-dot-notation)**, enclose the whole dotted field name in quotes. The following updates the `classes` array in the embedded `users` document.

Define an `updateClasses` function as follows:

```
var updateClasses = function(db, callback) {
   db.collection('classes').updateOne(
        { "users.email" : "somebody@gmail.com" },
        {
            "$push": {
                "users.$.classes": {
                    "className": "CCCC3333",
                    "marks": [75, 85, 95],
                    "grades": [20, 30, 50]
                }
            }
        }, function(err, results) {
        console.log(results);
        callback();
   });
};
```

Call the `updateClasses` function.

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    // handle error
    if (err) handleError(err);

    updateClasses(db, function() {
        db.close();
    });
});
```

To delete class `"AAAA1111"` without affecting the rest of the document, use teh **[`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)** operator which removes from an existing array all instances of a value or values that match a specified condition:

```
db.collection('classes').updateOne(
    { "users.email" : "somebody@gmail.com" },
    {
        "$push": {
            "users.$.classes": {
                "className": "AAAA1111"
            }
        }
    }, function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
    callback();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a `class` to `classes` you can retrieve the document, push the new class array into `classes` and save the document:

```
users.findOne({
    email: 'somebody@gmail.com'
}).exec(function(err, user) {
    var newClass = {
        className: 'CCCC3333',
        marks: [75, 85, 95],
        grades: [20, 30, 50]
    };

    user.classes.push(newClass);
    user.save(function(err) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        console.log('Updated!');
    });
});
```